How to fix disk space error?
I have dual booted my 1Tb ssd to 300 Gb for my Ubuntu Linux. But in my windows 11 os it is showing only 2Gb for Ubuntu drive.Why?

I'm guessing here that Windows can show your /boot/efi partition, but that your / partition is not shown since Windows does not recognize the filesystem. This would probably be normal.

Ubuntu can use many POSIX file-systems, none of which are native to the windows OS, thus many of them cannot be read by windows at all (some can be read by some tools in windows that aren't installed by default, with functionality needing to be added to a default windows install).  You've provided no details of your Ubuntu product, or release of that product, nor what file-systems you're actually using (Servers can have different defaults to Desktops) let alone complexities of encryption (multiple types here too). You've provided almost no specifics as I see it.

Windows 11 supports the FAT filesystem which is used to format the /boot/efi partition which contains Ubuntu's grub bootloader, but it does not support the ext4 filesystem which is the default filesystem used to install the rest of the Ubuntu operating system. Therefore Windows is able to recognize only 2GB out of the 300GB which you have allocated and partitioned for Ubuntu on your 1TB SSD.
